# Heroku Requirements for Django

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy my Django project via Heroku. I have done: `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to generate requirement file.

While deploying I am getting the below error-

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apturl==0.5.2 (from -r /tmp/build_3fb1fde9_/requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for apturl==0.5.2 (from -r /tmp/build_3fb1fde9_/requirements.txt (line 1))
```

I tried to do `pip install` that in my system but again I am getting exception- `requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for URL: https://pypi.org/simple/apturl/`

Note- This is the first time I am deploying my project. I guessed I need to do `pip install` so I did. If I should be doing something else to fulfill the requirement.

Thanks!

Comment: apturl doesn't look like to by a pypi package. It looks like a system package. For example, in Linux, you would install it with `apt-get install apturl`

Comment: when I am trying to do- `sudo apt-get install apturl==0.5.2`. It's showing me ``` E: Unable to locate package apturl= ```

On doing  `sudo apt-get install apturl=0.5.2`. it's showing me ``` E: Version '0.5.2' for 'apturl' was not found```

And on doing-  `sudo apt-get install apturl`. It's showing requirement already meet but still I am not able to deploy my project and getting same error at heroku